# unit test for a line of code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I'm new at writing unit tests and I'm writing unit tests for my bot code.
I have this part bothering me :

```
const accessToken = (() => {
  if (process.argv.length !== 3) {
    console.log('usage: node main/implementation');
    process.exit(1);
  }
  return process.argv[2];
})();
```

istanbul is showing me that this line `return process.argv[2];` is not covered, but I don't have any idea about writing a unit test for that line.
Any idea ?

Comment: You need to pass 3 parameters to your IIFE, like const accessToken = (()=>{..code})('a', 'b', 'c');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If istanbul says that this line is not covered, it means that all your tests cases match

```
process.argv.length !== 3
```

and so none of your test is going to this line

```
return process.argv[2];
```

Before fixing it, you should ask yourself if it is relevant to add a test for this line (100% coverage is not always necessary).

If you want to fix it, maybe you can try to set a value of process.argv. (This is just an idea, I'm not sure you can set the value of process.argv like this). Here is a pseudo-code

```
const fakeArgv = [1, 2, 3];
process.argv = fakeArgv;

it('should return third argv', () => {
  expect(accessToken).to.equal(3)
})
```

Comment: If I delete "return process.argv[2];", my app doesn't work anymore ^^'
So i think that all testes are going to that line, and none is going to this one : process.argv.length !== 3

Comment: What command do you run to start your app ? What command do you run to start your tests ? If the command is different, you can have arguments in your app but not in your tests

Comment: from my package.json :
"start": "node build/implementation.js AEDARC6WSMQNHLEA6I2TNFOT7GEJ2VOH"

"test": "mocha test/test.spec.js",

Comment: So this is what I said, your tests do not have arguments, so your tests is not going to the last line